# How to setup and use lcurses (curses for Lua)?

Tags: lua, ncurses

I'm not very good at manual installation. I want to use [lcurses](http://web.ist.utl.pt/tiago.dionizio/lua/lcurses.html), a binding of curses for Lua in a program, with `require('curses')`. When I run `make` in the lcurses directory, there is an error complaining about the path `LUA`, defined in the Makefile, not existing.

I think I need to figure out where the correct Lua directory is, but I don't know where it might be. I've searched with Nautilus and its searching thingy, but I couldn't find a directory named "Lua" that had `include`, `lib`, and `bin` subdirectories, all of which seem to be wanted in the Makefile.

I'm not sure that the directory is the only issue, though. How do I set it up? I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, if that helps, and I've never managed to get a Lua `require` thingy to work.

And this is what the beginning of the Makefile looks like:

```
# makefile for lcurses library for Lua

# dist location
DISTDIR=$(HOME)/dist
TMP=/tmp

# change these to reflect your Lua installation
LUA=/usr/bin/lua
LUAINC= $(LUA)/include
LUALIB= $(LUA)/lib
LUABIN= $(LUA)/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Most distributions install Lua next to all other programs in `/usr`, not to a directory of its own; **`LUA = /usr`** seems to be the correct path here, at least on Arch.

If it is not, search for files `include/lua.h` or `lib/liblua.a`, after installing the proper `-dev` packages if necessary.

```
find / -name lua.h
```

Comment: Using "find / -name lua.h" brought up a directory of "/usr/include/lua5.1/lua.h". LUA = /usr did not work, I got a "No such file or directory" error, again.

Comment: @Uronym: From that result, it seems that you have to redefine the variables directly: `LUA = /usr`, `LUAINC = /usr/include/lua5.1`. For LUALIB, use the same command to find `liblua.a`, I am guessing `LUALIB = /usr/lib/lua5.1` though.

Comment: `LUA=/usr LUAINC= /usr/include/5.1 LUALIB= /usr/lib/lua5.1 LUABIN= /usr/bin/lua5.1` did not work, same error. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Uronym: No; `LUA=/usr` `LUAINC=/usr/include/lua5.1` `LUALIB=/usr/lib/lua5.1` `LUABIN=/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Lua .deb package, you should have no problem. The following script should tell you where Lua is looking for modules of both the Lua and compiled C varieties:

```
strPaths = package.path .. "\r?\n"
strPaths = strPaths .. package.cpath 
strPaths = string.gsub(strPaths, ";", "\r?\n")
print strPaths
```

You can also set a custom path using an environmental variable. See the Lua Reference manual documentation for `package.path` and `package.cpath`.

Finally, a script can set its own path to a module. See http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Setting-LUA-PATH-from-lua-script-tc7649425.html